# increment numbers during certain hours of the day javascript

Tags: javascript

Pretty much looking to increment the amount of money earned during the hours of 9 - 5:30 every day, which holds its value from the start of work.

So in essence if its past 5:30 at night the 'earning of money' stops until 9:30 the next day and it increments per second until 5:30.

Here is what is present so far;

```js
//Different toolkits for different browsers. If none work, set to null.
var animFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || null;

//Creating instances of canvas and the canvas' 2d drawing, allowing us to manipulate it in JS
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var startDate = new Date(2016, 07, 01, 00, 00, 00);

var currentDate = 0;

var valuePerSec = 0.00088776157;
var valuePerSecTax = 0.00307364672;

var todaysDate = new Date();
var todaysWorkStart = new Date(todaysDate.getFullYear(), todaysDate.getMonth(), todaysDate.getDay(), 09, 00, 00);
var yesterday = new Date(todaysDate.getFullYear(), todaysDate.getMonth(), todaysDate.getDay() - 1, 09, 00, 00);

//Loops through to draw the graphics. this function is called through the recursiveAnim function
function mainLoop() {
    clearScreen();
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeSinceDate = Math.floor((currentTime - startDate.getTime()) / 1000);
    var yesterdaySinceDate = Math.floor((yesterday.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000);
    //var daysSinceBegin = //

    textPart(timeSinceDate, yesterdaySinceDate);
}

function textPart(timeSinceDate, yesterdaySinceDate) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#008000";
    ctx.font = "70px Helvetica";
    ctx.fillText("£" + (timeSinceDate * valuePerSec).toFixed(2), 150, 260);
    ctx.fillText(Math.round(yesterdaySinceDate / 86400), 250, 150);

    ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
    ctx.fillText(yesterday, 150, 400);
    ctx.fillText("money", c.width - 175, c.height - 6);
}

function clearScreen() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#33cc33";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}

//This loops the animation frames for creating animation
function recursiveAnim() {
    mainLoop();
    animFrame(recursiveAnim);
}
animFrame(recursiveAnim);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>money</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this counts every second of the day with 'valuePerSec', I want 'valuePerSecTax' to only increment per second between the times of 9:00 - 5:30 everyday and add it to the amount of money earned every day since the 'startDate'.

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: @AxelH Updated the original.

Comment: I don't see any condition in you code, so it won't check the actual time to see if you are in the "payed time" or not. Have you thought about a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it seems you are trying to use a hammer to kill an ant... I will not implement any logic to do your calculation but will give you an idea on how to structure your code.

```js
//new Date().getTime will return timestamp something like 1470404780537
 
//Do calculation every 10 miliseconds
setInterval(calculateIncrease(new Date().getTime()), 10);

//Function do to what ever income increase
function calculateIncrease(time_stamp) {

    if (is_valid(time_stamp) {

        //do calculations
      }
      //else wait
    }

    function is_valid(time_stamp) {

      //write the logic to check if the time is between 9:30 am and 5:30 pm
    }
```